# Adding large folder to git repository without caching to repository?

Tags: git, file, github, repository

I have a repository with about 55GB of contents, with binary files that are less than 100MB each (so no LFS mode) from a project which has almost filled up an entire hard drive. I am trying to add all of the contents to a git repo and push it to GitHub but every time I do

```
git add .
```

in the folder with my contents after initializing and setting my remote, git starts caching all the files to .git/objects, making the .git folder grow in size rapidly. All the files are binaries, so git cannot stage changes between versions anyway, so there is no reason to cache versions.

Is there any way, such as editing the git attributes or changing something about how files are staged in the git repository, to only just add indexes or references to files in the repository rather than cache them into the .git folder, while also being able to push all the data to GitHub?

Comment: This is precisely what git-lfs was developed for.

Comment: I mean, like, you are literally describing the high level problem that git-lfs was designed to solve.

Comment: I am trying git lfs mode now, with some help from #git on FreeNode IRC, it seems to still be doing the same problem, but I will wait it out to see what its like

Comment: Staged files are actually a commit object with no id. If you have 55GB of contents, that first commit is going to be 55GB. Git must stage all the contents in order to create the commit. Maybe try committing the files in batches? Run `git gc` in between large commits. This helps speed things up, but certainly doesn't reduce the repository size.

Answer (score 0):

Directly login into GitHub using your browser and upload the files through the browser, this will completely eliminate the use of git, now make git ignore all the media files using `.gitignore` file. Now only the binaries will be managed by git.

Hope this helps!